# Modify Object Method in Python - Ruby like '!'

Tags: python, ruby

Is there an operator in python that allows you to make a method you call, actually modify the object, making it equal to its output?
Essentially what I am asking, is that if there is anything like the exclamation sign of ruby, but in python.

---

Example in ruby (Note that Ruby methods don't need brackets to be called if they have no arguments):

```
array = [2, 7, 1]
array.sort
```

> >>[1, 2, 7]

```
array
```

> >>[2, 7, 1]

```
array.sort!
```

> >>[1, 2, 7]

```
array
```

> >>[1, 2, 7]

---

Now, I know that in Python, or pretty much any language (including Ruby), you could just do:

```
array = sorted(array)
```

But I just wanted to know if there was a predefined specific way to achieve that

Comment: `array = array.sort` will assign the built-in method `sort` of list objects to the variable `array`, so you can't know that about Python.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP meant `array = array.sort()` since they're still thinking like Ruby code where brackets are optional. However, I'll let them fix their question.

Comment: I don't know about Ruby, but in Python, you have to actually call that method instead of just reference it, which requires `()`. Also, `array.sort()` modifies `array` and returns `None`, while `sorted(array)` returns a sorted array while leaving the original `array` unchanged.

Comment: yes, i meant what @Soviut said, my bad, editing now

Comment: Still not right. `array = array.sort()` will assign `None` to `array` (for the reasons @TigerhawkT3 mentioned about what the built-in  `list.sort` method returns).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there isn't. Like most languages, whether a method on an array mutates or returns a new array is completely up to the language implementer.

It's less of an operator and more of a naming convention to denote dangerous or destructive methods. It isn't enforced in any way and you could define any method you like with a trailing `!`. However, Ruby is somewhat unique in their implementation of explicitly upholding this as a formal convention.

Comment: Most likely to prevent newer members with low reputation from accepting the first answer they see and instead making them choose the best answer given.

Comment: In Ruby it's not even "immutable vs. mutable" consistently; the `!` suffix is better thought of as "this method does something more potentially dangerous or destructive than the function without it". It's definitely just a naming convention, and not enforced in any way.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan I updated my answer to include those remarks.